# Transfer Sharepoint WebPart data to application page

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have created a visual web part that has one entry form, it contains 10 textboxes and a submit button  to insert the data.

Now on click of submit button it redirects to another page(page is application page deployed under layout folder of same site. this page is added in same web part solution by adding new item).

I'm able to redirect to application page using **SPUtility.Redirect().** but not sure about best approach to pass the data from web part page to application.

I think that query string is not a good solution. Also enabling session is manual work on each environment(as i experienced that in one server when i created session variable i got an error to enable it, but in other dev server i was able to do that).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done this using a public class in user control .cs page and defined all fields as static variables in side the class. now I'm able to access them in application page added inside layout folder of same project solution. Not sure if it is right approach , but it works